# What is fish plating a frame?

Tags: hotrod, frame, welding

When building a frame I've heard people refer to adding a fish plate.  What does fish plating a frame do and what exactly is it?

Comment: Someone explain the downvote??

Comment: I guess its because you answered your own question almost immediately.  Some people take exception to that, because it doesn't give anyone else a chance to answer.  Its about rep-whoring basically.   Other times its perceived as "not a real question" that is now adding to clutter on the site, obscuring real questions.  On the other hand, SE specifically allows this.

Comment: Wasnt trying to do that.  We had a convo about welding in chat and two members asked what it was so i thought it would be a great chance for a Q&A.

Comment: This is not only allowed, but encouraged.  There are some who still don't like it, but they are in the wrong, not you.  Go ahead and continue to post such good questions and answers (I'm glad you added an image!) and ignore the downvoters.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking for more information. Note that the "Ask Question" page has a box to answer your own question - this isn't just allowed, is specifically supported and encouraged, so don't get discouraged by people who disagree.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fish plating a frame is typically used when someone is building a custom frame and two pieces of steel are met and a plate is created to overlap both pieces to add structure support:

[image]